# Catch ElementClickInterceptedException in Selenium with C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, testing, appium

I'm trying to catch a ElementClickInterceptedException in C#, but it apppears I'm doing something wrong since it doesn't go to the catch code line when I get that exception while debugging. Strange thing is that if the test runs normally, it doesn't throw the exception at that point, but when it runs in debug mode, it does...[image]

I try catching the exception because Selenium keeps throwing it and I don't know what to do to solve it.

Comment: ElementClickInterceptedException is the inner exception, not the highest level exception. Put catch(Exception ex) and breakpoint just after to find it

Comment: @Monofuse Yes, just realized that after I posted the question. I already left the code that solves the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I have been catching the wrong exception all along. Anyway, I'll leave the code that worked for me when I got a TargetInvocationException or ElementClickInterceptedException so anyone facing the same issue can solve it like I did:

```
public bool clickBtn(IWebElement btnElement)
        {
            bool result = false;
            int attempts = 0;
            while (attempts < 10)
            {
                try
                {
                    waitForClickable(btnElement);
                    btnElement.Click();
                    result = true;
                    break;
                }
                catch (TargetInvocationException e)
                {
                }
                catch (StaleElementReferenceException e)
                {
                }
                attempts++;
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

I think you can get rid of the second catch and it will work all the same :)

Also, I leave the code for the "waitForClickable" method:

```
internal void waitForClickable(IWebElement button)
        {
            try
            {
                wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(button));
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException e)
            {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("It wasn't possible to click the element.\n" + e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a `Click()` method for my framework that takes care of exceptions, retries, etc. Also, you don't need the `Thread.Sleep()` in there since the `WebDriverWait` takes care of waiting for the element to be clickable already. In my code, I replaced the loop and counter with a pure timeout in seconds.

```
/// <summary>
/// Clicks the element.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="locator">The By locator for the desired element.</param>
/// <param name="timeOut">[Optional] How long to wait for the element (in seconds). The default is 10s.</param>
public void Click(By locator, int timeOut = 10)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    while (DateTime.Now < now.AddSeconds(timeOut))
    {
        try
        {
            new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(locator)).Click();

            return;
        }
        catch (Exception e) when (e is ElementClickInterceptedException || e is StaleElementReferenceException)
        {
            // do nothing, loop again
        }
    }

    throw new Exception($"Not able to click element <{locator}> within {timeOut}s.");
}
```